# C static variables in python multi-process

Tags: python, static-variables, multiprocess

Here I have a function written in C++ call *foo* and make it callable (*foo_wrapper*) from python by using a python wrapper written in C (wrapper.c).

In wrapper.c, I have a static global variable "x", which is used and updated by *foo*.

Now everything works fine when I call *foo* from python within one process.

However, while I use **multiprocess** module in python, even foo is called from main process, this "x" value is NOT as it should be!! The calling procedure is like this:

```
P=Process(target=myf, args=(a,))
P.start()
foo_wrapper()
P.join()
```

my question is: when fork() is called, i.e. multiple processes are launched, how python handle the stack or heap of parent/child process? How could I make the value of "x" right to the main process (or parent process)?

Comment: 'this "x" value is NOT as it should be!!'  -- Can you give a little more description?  What is wrong with it?

Comment: x is initialized once. But after the fork, the x value in the main process is not loaded, i.e, not the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

C++ global variables are only global to a single process.  If you are using the `multiprocessing` module, then by definition you will have multiple processes, each with their own view of the global variable.  Python doesn't do anything special to affect this behaviour.

Assuming you have control of the C++ code, I would suggest refactoring it to make this global state visible to Python in a form that Python can serialise and deserialise.  You could then pass the state between processes where needed (e.g. using one of the queue classes from `multiprocessing`).

Comment: cool! but could you explain a little bit, why after fork, the global variables which is available to the main process (parent process) is no longer available to it after fork()? I thought the new processes are just copies of the parent process and the parent process is still the same as before, i.e. all the stack and heap are still in the same places as before fork. thanks a lot~

Comment: After the fork, each process should have their own independent copy of the global variable.  It shouldn't have altered the value though.  I can't be any more specific, since you didn't say what sort of information is held in the global.